# Categorical interpretation of beta-reduction for mu abstractions in lambda-mu calculus

Tags: type-theory, category-theory

I've been reading the Peter Selinger's article "Control Categories and Duality: On the Categorical Semantics of the Lambda-Mu Calculus". I'm wondering about the categorical interpretation of the reduction rules. In particular, I'm trying to demonstrate that the left and right sides of $$[\alpha']\mu \alpha^A. M = M[\alpha'/\alpha]$$ have the same categorical interpretation.

I'm assuming I need a substitution lemma for covariables. Though I haven't proven it, I'm assuming this lemma says that if $\Gamma \vdash M : B \mid \alpha : A, \alpha' : A, \Delta$ then $\Gamma \vdash M[\alpha'/\alpha] : B \mid \alpha' : A, \Delta$, and furthermore $$\require{HTML} [[~M[\alpha'/\alpha]~]] = [[~M~]];([[~B~]]~\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(180deg)}{ \text{\&} }~\triangledown_{[[~A~]]}~\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(180deg)}{ \text{\&} }~[[ \Delta ]])$$

Referring to table 4, we can construct direct categorical interpretation of the typing judgment for $[\alpha']\mu \alpha_i^A. M$
$$[[~[\alpha']\mu \alpha^A. M~]] = [[~M~]];(r^\circ_A~\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(180deg)}{ \text{\&} }~[[~\Delta~]]);(w_i~\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(180deg)}{ \text{\&} }~\Delta);\triangledown_{\Delta};r_{\Delta}$$

where $r^\circ_A$ above is the inverse of $r_A$. How do I prove that these two morphisms are equal?